# Opencv's javacameraview failing to open camera on Android Marshmallow Devices

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera, android-6.0-marshmallow

I've developed an android application which is using Opencv v2.4.10. I have used javacameraview in my capture activity and it is working fine on devices which has api level lower than 23. But protected boolean initializeCamera(int width, int height) function returns false on devices with api level 23 (Android Marshmallow).

I couldn't find any possible solution for this error.Has anyone encountered this problem? How can i solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you requesting the permission at runtime as is required by Android 6.0+?

Comment: Thank you for comment . Yes it was runtime permission issue. I have solved it by requesting permissions on runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to request permission for access to the camera at runtime by adding it on enableView() method on JavaCameraView object.